# Recursive function returns reverse values

Tags: php, recursion

Hi I need one clarification in php recursive function, please see my code below.

```
<?php 
function test($count=1){
    if($count <5){
        echo $count;
        test(++$count);
    }
    echo $count;
}
test();
?>
```

For the above function i am getting output like this 1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2
I know the logic for first 6 elements but i don't know how the reverse elements come. please explain me the logic

Answer (score 1):

Each iteration will print out its `$count` twice; once "on the way down" and once "on the way up". You have two `echo $count` statements; one that gets called before it calls a new `test()`, and once that is called after the recursion returns. Since `$count` is not a global variable, each iteration will keep its own value for `$count`

Comment: HI FSQ, i have declared the $count as global above the function. but still it shows the same result.

Comment: You should also remove the second `echo $count`. Also remember that `++$count` modifies the value of `$count`. So for a `test()` where `$count=4`, your second echo `$count` would print 5.

Answer (score 1):

The latter half of the output comes from the second `echo` statement.
You can add markers to the `echo`s to make things obvious:

```
<?php 
function test($count=1){
    if($count <5){
        echo "A:$count ";
        test(++$count);
    }
    echo "B:$count ";
}
test();
?>
// will print A:1 A:2 A:3 A:4 B:5 B:5 B:4 B:3 B:2
```

The following is a pseudo call graph that shows the `echo` order:

```
test(1) {
  echo A:1
  test(2) {
    echo A:2
    test(3) {
      echo A:3
      test(4) {
        echo A:4
        test(5) {
          echo B:5
        }
        echo B:5
      }
      echo B:4
    }
    echo B:3
  }
  echo B:2
}
```

Comment: hi i am getting only this ouput 1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2